# How do I construct a query to get a group id for a set of members?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want a query that will find a group that consists of exactly the members that are queried for. Furthermore, members can have aliases.

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Alias(
    id    VARCHAR(40),
    alias VARCHAR(40)
);

CREATE TABLE Group(
    group_id  VARCHAR(40),
    member_id VARCHAR(40)
);

Alias:
1 4
2 5
3 6

Group:
10 1
10 4
10 5
11 2
11 6
12 2
13 1
13 2
13 3
```

These are example queries and results

```
Query('1')           : NULL
Query('1', '2')      : '10' 
Query('5', '3')      : '11' 
Query('4', '5', '6') : '13'
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/ab3ac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is like a set-within-sets query, with the additional complication of aliases.  I like to solve these using `group by` with a `having` clause.

Here is the query:

```
select g.group_id
from `group` g left outer join
     (select id, alias
      from alias a
      union
      select alias, id
      from alias
     ) a
     on g.member_id = a.alias
group by g.group_id
having sum(g.member_id = '4' or a.id = '4') > 0 and
       sum(g.member_id = '5' or a.id = '5') > 0 and
       sum(g.member_id = '6' or a.id = '6') > 0 and
       count(distinct coalesce(min(a.id, a.alias), g.member_id)) = 3;
```

The first three conditions in the `having` clause test for each of the values you care about.  The query looks for aliases in both directions, by using the `union` in the alias clause.

The complicated `count()` expression is intended to count the number of distinct pairs.  An alias is counted using the minimum value in the alias.  This works for the four cases in the question.  You might actually want this `count()` expression:

```
count(distinct min(a.id, a.alias, g.member_id))
```

Comment: This query has some problems: primarily that if two ids alias each other it throws the count off. E.g. count(distinct g.member_id) of group 10 is three when in fact there are only two unique ids.

Comment: @chacham15 . . . That situation does not arise in the question.  There is no reason, based on the description, to assume that this could happen.

Comment: Huh? look at the example query: `Query('1', '2')      : '10' ` and the result of your query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/ab3ac/2 (or if you set the count to be 3 you get the other wrong answer: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/ab3ac/3 )